# dynamically Call an object that is not a control

Tags: vb.net

I use the following to get a control dynamically

```
 Dim theTextBox As TextBox = CType(Me.Controls(dynamicName + "TextBox"), TextBox)
```

Is there something similar for the objects that are not controls like the arrays. As a walk around I add the array to a dictionary. but is there something similar to    controls that includes non visual objects.

Comment: All controls get added to the `Controls` collection of their parent. That's how the parent knows to display them. Nothing else gets added to a collection like that as a matter of course so nothing else can be accessed like that.  If you're using a `Dictionary` then you are basically implementing the same thing for non-controls.

Comment: That said, using a `Dictionary` may or may not be the best option. If you were to explain the specific issue you're trying to address, rather than just asking a general question, then we could address that specific issue.  That's what this site is for. It is not for general questions.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Then there is no collection for non visual controls on a form. Is there a way to access an object in a way like "Me.[dynamicName].count". ?

Comment: No, there is no such collection because there is no need for such a collection.  As for the last question, why would you want to?  It's possible but it's not something that should be done unless absolutely required and it is rarely required. If you were to describe the problem you're actually trying to solve, rather than how you're trying to solve it, then we could provide the most appropriate advice.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for jmcilhinney for the discussion.
As I said before I solved my problem using a Dictionary but I use curious if there was I better way.
So as jmcilhinney said the answer to my question is no, there is no collection for non visual objects.